# Can a decider be built with 2 "opposite" recognizers?

Tags: turing-machines, formal-languages

If I have 2 turing machines, A and B, let's say that A accepts every word in a language L that has a property P, while B does the opposite, it accepts every word that does not have the property P. I don't know if A and B would reject in their complementary cases, all I can say is that they are recognizers. Can I build a Turing Machine that decides if a word is in the language L?

I was thinking of making an abstract turing machine C composed of both A and B where, if a word "enters" C, then this word would "enter" both A and B at the same time and consequently accepting the moment A accepts and rejecting when B accepts, and thus, always halting? Does this follow? or I am missing something?

Sorry if I'm being too informal on my explanations.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the proof for this theorem: If a language L and its complement are semi-decidable, L is decidable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean, but it seems like A could accept any word with P and B could accept any word with Not P, without either having any reference to L whatsoever.